# TCPDF - How to generate a TTF file from PHP?

Tags: tcpdf, truetype

I am using TCPDF 6.0.20, PHP 5.3.8.

Since my PDF will contain some Chinese Character (Simplified and Traditional), I decide to use font name: `cid0cs`.

Now, since a lot of users replied that they don't have that font installed, I need to embed this font to the PDF.

However, in http://www.tcpdf.org/fonts.php it says how to embed a TTF file using `addTTFfont()`, but **NO WAY** to create that font.

The only file that I found in `tcpdf/fonts/` is `cid0cs.php`, which is NOT a TTF file.

I tried to run the script in `tcpdf/tools/tcpdf_addfont.php` and use the command line below:

> c:\tcpdf>php tools/tcpdf_addfont.php -t CID0CS -o . -i fonts/cid0cs.php

and it returns:

> --- ERROR: can't add fonts/cid0cs.php

How can I create the `cid0cs.ttf` file so that I can embed it using `addTTFfont()`?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and record the process in my blog post below:

http://alucard-blog.blogspot.hk/2013/06/tcpdf-how-to-display-chinese-character.html

The key point is: I found the font that can display Traditional and Simplified Chinese.

Comment: Please insert **here** the content of your blog, it's not that long, and will ensure its availability.

Answer (score 0):

1. cmd and run php
2. run this command : \ABSOLUTE PATH TO\tcpdf_addfont.php -i \ABSOLUTE PATH TO\myfont.ttf
3. if it works fine, you will find 3 files of myfont in /TCPDF/fonts
4. you might find some help here : http://queirozf.com/entries/adding-a-custom-font-to-tcpdf